# Mountain Lion TexLive 2013 font installation problem

Tags: fonts, texlive, mac

I'm stuck here for hours trying to install fonts for TeXLive 2013. I did the same stuff as always:

1. unzip to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`
2. run `sudo mktexlsr`
3. then `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map 5ch.map`

After running the last line I'm getting message:

> ```
> updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/sFun) to root's actual home (/var/root).
> updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
> updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
> dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
> pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
> dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
> pxdvi output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"
>
> ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
>   5ch.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
>
>   Did you run mktexlsr?
>
>   You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
>     --syncwithtrees.
> ```

I also tried the same stuff for the texmf in the user library - same error message:(

Comment: It's better to append the line `Map 5ch.map` to the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` file (create it if it doesn't exist yet). Then simply run `sudo updmap-sys`

Comment: Hm, I remove Map 5ch.map from the 2013/.../updmap.cfg and append as u said, then run updmap-sys: no error message, but font seems to be not there: aTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/5ch/m/n' undefined(Font)

Comment: That's a different problem: there should be a `t15ch.fd` file in the distribution or a `.sty` file with the necessary `\DeclareFontShape` commands

Comment: But I have t15ch.fd file in the distribution with \DeclareFontShape{T1}{5ch}{m}{n}{
   <-> 5chr8t
}{}

Comment: Try doing `kpsewhich t15ch.fd` from the Terminal; what's the answer?

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: Thus either the file is not in the correct place or `mktexlsr` didn't succeed.

Comment: I install this fonts few times before on Lion with TexLive 2012 it has never been a problem.

Comment: AFAIK the general advise for MacOS is to use MacTeX, not TeXLive directly.

Comment: Actually I'm using MacTex, I wrote TexLive since font management are the same for MacTex and TexLive?

Answer (score 2):

I finally installed my fonts. Somehow it does not work with updmap-sys. I just installed the fonts to my Library (`~/Library/texmf`) then create the updmap config file there (`~/Library/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`) and execute the `updmap` command.